# How should I design a NodeJs REST server where I need authentication for certain requests?

Tags: node.js, rest, security, authentication, authorization

I'm trying to build a server with some security. Let's say I have a file list component and a image viewer that I don't have access to and which make constant requests to my server. I'd like to filter those somehow based on who is making the request.Is there any way to check server-side if the client that's making the request has authorization while still having the server in a RESTful state and by not modifying the requests themselves?

Comment: This file list component that's accessing your server - does it have knowledge of who the user is? And more importantly - does it relay this info to you?
There should be no problem with "not modifying the requests themselves", it's just a matter of a simple middleware on your secured route that checks if the requestor is authorized or not.

Comment: @Zlatko Yes both the image viewer and the file list know the user. Thing is I'm using a library (openlayers3) for the image viewer and I can't modify the request headers or such ( I just simply give it a url where my tiles are )

Comment: So your REST API is giving the user the link to openlayers tile?

Comment: @Zlatko No I have a rule on how I store the tiles so the links are generated by the client, and till now I've made that link public using express static. Log-in with Basic auth works since chrome sends the info on every request but not so good with Digest or something a little bit more safe.

Comment: Sorry, still not grasping the whole picture. You have a client (web page). It includes openlayers3 lib. It creates a link to a tile, then calls your server with a request for that tile. Something like that? Did you start something like a user session before you got to this link generation part? If you have a cookie or something that the client already used, another request to your server will still bring in that cookie. MAybe that's something you can use.
In any case, I'm not getting the scenario yet. Maybe show some code example (on the client and on the server) and let us know what to secure

Comment: @Zlatko I have a few pictures on the server-side and some basic rules for storing them ( folder name etc. ). The client enters the page, gets the number of pictures on the server, generates and checks every folder ( there is a config.json for every picture ) and if the picture exists, it adds a item in the file list. Thing is I want some pictures to be private.

Comment: Aha, it's more clear now. But you still need an authentication strategy. If you cannot use username/password, you have to make one up. It cna be a simple cookie, by a custom header, by just remembering the IP address in the last 10 minutes and only allow access if that same address and user-agent were on the page within last 10 minutes... Really depends. If you control the browsers, you can have people use chrome and override the requests with a service worker to provide some auth. The key question is: when a user makes this picture request - do you already have auth?

Comment: @Zlatko After some research I kinda decided to go with user/pass , encrypt it and afterwards use a random sessionID. Thnx a bunch tho, let me know if you have other ideas :)